# Oracle - denie columns in where clause

Tags: oracle, where-clause

Is there a way to disable/restrict/alert-when-using some column in Oracle in a where clauses?

The reason that I'm asking this is because I have a very complex system (~30 services span cross millions of lines of code with thousends of sqls in it, in a sensitive production environment) working with an Oracle DB I need to migrate from using one column that is part of a key (and have a very not uniqu name) to another column.

Simple search is impossible....
The steps I'm having are:

1. populate new column
2. Add indexes on with the second column whenever there's an index with the first one.
3. Migrate all uses in where caluses from old to new column
4. Stop reading from the first column
5. Stop writing to the first column
6. Delete the column

I'm currently done step 3 and want to verify I've found all of the cases.

Comment: Looks like refactoring, which should be performed in the isolated environment (QA or copy of production) before you apply it to the prod. All the references you miss by simple  queries on `dba_source`, `dba_views` etc may be found using failed statements from the application side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're replacing one column with another. Which benefit do you expect once you're done? How will that improve *overall experience* with that application? I hope it is worth the effort.

As of your question: query `user_source` (or expand it to all_source or even `dba_source`, but you'll need additional privileges to do that) and see where's that *very not unique name* used. Something like this:

```
SQL> select * from user_source where lower(text) like '%empno%';

NAME            TYPE          LINE TEXT
--------------- ------------ ----- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
P_RAISE         PROCEDURE       22        WHERE empno = par_empno;
P_RAISE         PROCEDURE       14     WHERE empno = par_empno;
P_RAISE         PROCEDURE        1 PROCEDURE p_raise (par_empno IN emp.empno%TYPE)
GET_LIST        FUNCTION         7          'select empno, ename, job, sal from emp where deptno = 10 order by '

SQL>
```

Comment: Some statements may be placed, for example, in the PL/SQL block of scheduled jobs or audit policies, so this task is more complex than `dba_source`.

Comment: Not to mention a front-end application, @astentx. I still think that I'd rather not do it (unless I must). Lucky me, I don't have to.